# PSQL Query issue how i can group these results. ERROR message inside

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to group my query results. The table I am performing the query on contains two fields piste_name and lift_name both make up the composite key for the table.

This is the error message that I get:

> ERROR:  column "lift_location.piste_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The queries that I am trying are:

```
SELECT piste_name, lift_name  FROM lift_location 
    GROUP BY lift_location.lift_name;
```

and:

```
SELECT piste_name, lift_name  FROM lift_location 
    GROUP BY lift_name;
```

I think the problem arises because piste_name is also part of the composite key so it needs to be part of the grouping, but is there a work around for this?

I expect my query to return the piste_names and which lift access them but i want them to be displayed in terms of the lifts rather than a selection of piste_names then the list.

Currently, I have:

```
    piste_name | lift_name
--------------------------------
      piste 1  |  lift x
      piste 1  |  lift y
      piste 2  |  lift x
      piste 2  |  lift z
```

And I want my query to display it in this format:

```
   lift_name  | piste_name
--------------------------------
      lift x  |  piste 1
      lift x  |  piste 2
      lift y  |  piste 1
      lift z  |  piste 2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you messed up grouping and ordering of your results.

```
SELECT lift_name, piste_name FROM lift_location ORDER BY lift_name, piste_name
```

This delivers the results you want. So why the **group by**?

Comment: i was using GROUP not ORDER thanks. I havent done a huge amount of SQL so it was a rookie mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just not

```
SELECT lift_name, piste_name  
FROM lift_location 
GROUP BY lift_name, piste_name
ORDER BY lift_name, piste_name;
```